# Running Flask on Apache - CentOS

Tags: python, apache, flask, centos, mod-wsgi

I setup a very simple flask application to test a deployment in Apache on CentOS 6 but I'm getting the follow error:

```
[Sat Apr 26 12:44:20 2014] [error] mod_wsgi (pid=29782): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/sites/rtdsllc/rtdsllc.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Apr 26 12:44:20 2014] [error] mod_wsgi (pid=29782): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/sites/rtdsllc/rtdsllc.wsgi'.
[Sat Apr 26 12:44:20 2014] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Apr 26 12:44:20 2014] [error] File "/var/www/html/sites/rtdsllc/rtdsllc.wsgi", line 10, in <module>
[Sat Apr 26 12:44:20 2014] [error]     from rtdsllc import app as application
[Sat Apr 26 12:44:20 2014] [error] ImportError: cannot import name app
```

This is my wsgi file:

```
activate_this = '/var/www/virtualenvs/default/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

path = '/var/www/html/sites/rtdsllc'

import sys
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

from rtdsllc import app as application
```

Here is my virtual host config:

```
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:8086>

    WSGIDaemonProcess rtdsllc user=apache group=apache threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /test /var/www/html/sites/rtdsllc/rtdsllc.wsgi

    ErrorLog logs/rtdsllc-error_log
    CustomLog logs/rtdsllc-access_log common

    <Directory /var/www/html/sites/rtdsllc/rtdsllc>
        WSGIProcessGroup rtdsllc
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my flask application:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)      

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=False)
```

And finally here is my folder structure:

```
rtdsllc/
├── rtdsllc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   └── js
│   └── templates
│       ├── base.html
│       └── index.html
└── rtdsllc.wsgi
```

What gives? I've tried various combinations of settings to no avail. What is the proper way of setting up a Flask app in apache?

**EDIT**

`ls -las rtdsllc/rtdsllc`:

```
4 drwxr-xr-x. 4 apache apache 4096 Apr 26 13:07 .
4 drwxr-xr-x. 3 apache apache 4096 Apr 25 22:54 ..
0 -rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache    0 Apr 25 20:57 __init__.py
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache  134 Apr 25 22:55 __init__.pyc
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache  190 Apr 26 12:48 routes.py
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache  521 Apr 26 13:07 routes.pyc
4 drwxr-xr-x. 5 apache apache 4096 Apr 25 20:14 static
4 drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache 4096 Apr 25 20:19 templates
```

Comment: Are the directories/files readable to the Apache user?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Yes sir. All files are owned by `apache:apache`.

Comment: It isn't just the files, but the directories. What is the output of 'ls -las rtdsllc/rtdsllc'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In doing:

```
from rtdsllc import app as application
```

it will be importing:

```
rtdsllc/rtdsllc/__init__.py
```

According to your directory listing:

```
0 -rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache    0 Apr 25 20:57 __init__.py
```

that file is empty and has not 'app' object in it to drag in via the import.

Which file is the following in?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Right now it isn't in the place that you are trying to import it from.

---

UPDATE 1

Use:

```
from rtdsllc.routes import app as application
```

if you 'app' object is in 'rtdsllc.routes'.

Comment: I have that in routes.py. What is the proper way of doing it?